# How to reload checkout page after applying the coupon code or removing the coupon code magento 2?

Tags: magento2, coupon-codes, checkout-page, custom-theme

> I am facing an issue related page  refresh on checkout page and it is
>   solving after refreshing page when discount applied or removed.

Comment: You can modify the code like apply promo code and remove in ajax action

Comment: this link worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998033/how-to-force-update-refresh-shipping-methods-on-checkout-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link is in working condition
https://alanstorm.com/refresh-shipping-rates-for-the-magento-2-checkout/